# How can I substitute my own custom dynamic scaffolding methods

Tags: grails, grails-controller

My grails app has to define some additional behaviour for many of the standard dynamic scaffolding methods for each domain class.

I know I can duplicate the methods I need to add to for each controller, and indeed that is what I currently do. This does mean that my custom code is obscured by the boilerplate scaffolding.

I have tried importing and modifying the templates as well but they only seem to get involved if I generate static scaffolding in my controllers. Needless to say this doesn't help much.

Interceptors don't seem to be what I want either as they enclose the action rather than being inserted into it. I thought about intercepting the GORM call in some fashion but that isn't really what I want either.

What I really want to do is replace the base dynamic scaffolding methods with ones that have a hook in the places I want to be able to modify.

The following shows an example of what I am trying to achieve

```
    // standard "save" dynamic scaffold method decorated with hooks for custom code
    def save() {
        def ${propertyName} = new ${className}(params)

        saveBeforeSave(${propertyName})

        if (!${propertyName}.save(flush: true)) {
            render(view: "create", model: [${propertyName}: ${propertyName}])
            return
        }

        saveAfterSave(${propertyName})

        flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: '${domainClass.propertyName}.label', default: '${className}'), ${propertyName}.id])
        redirect(action: "show", id: ${propertyName}.id)
    }

    // Placeholders hooks to be overridden in controller as necessary
    def saveBeforeSave(${propertyName}) {
    }
    def saveAfterSave(${propertyName}) {
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you simple use the command:

```
grails install-templates
```

Then modify the controller ?
[Guide](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/scaffolding.html) and [Reference](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/install-templates.html).

Just configure your controller with

```
static scaffold = *MODEL*
```

and apply your modifications to `/src/templates/scaffolding/Controller.groovy`

There is no need to generate to use generate-controller

Comment: As I noted above, from what I can tell this modifies the static scaffolding i.e. I can add my modifications and then generate-controller but it writes **everything**. I don't want to see hundreds of lines of boilerplate just to add a couple of lines of custom code, especially given that I won't be able to find my custom code in the mess.

Comment: That seems to have done it. Strange that I tried it before and it didn't work then. I did have "static scaffold = true" rather than "static scaffold = domainclass" maybe that makes a difference?

Comment: @MichaelRutherfurd could you share the complete code? I'm trying to do the same, but w/o success. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just finished an article about writing custom scaffolding behavior. The inner workings are copied from the grails source code scaffolding plugin. You can take a look at the actual [grails code here](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-scaffolding/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/scaffolding/ScaffoldingGrailsPlugin.groovy), and [my article](http://0x0313.blogspot.de/2012/11/grails-custom-controller-scaffolding.html).

Comment: What exactly does your article say?  What happens if link rot occurs?