# Grails admin (similar to Django's)

Tags: grails, groovy, django-admin, admin

I was wondering if some sort of equivalent of the Django admin exists for Grails. If I understand correctly (I am new to Groovy and Grails), the way you are supposed to generate an admin area in Grails is by scaffolding, which is at the end just automatic code generation.

In contrast, frameworks like Django and Symfony1 provide an application for admin tasks. This application can be customized (in Python for Django and YAML in Symfony) to change the way items are shown, which fields are present in the list view, the order in which they appear, which fields are searchable and so on.

Automatic code generation has some disadvantages over this approach. First, it increases code duplication. As a consequence, there are more places to edit to customize the admin. After you have done your customization, you cannot generate code anymore, so for instance if you change the fields of a model, you have to manually change its admin to reflect this: doing scaffold again will overwrite your customizations.

> Does it exist an application for Grails that generates an admin area without relying on code generation?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the Dynamic scaffolding?

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/scaffolding.html

(which you can make even hotter with http://grails.org/plugin/angular-scaffolding )

Comment: Well, the problem with dynamic scaffolding, if I understand correctly, is that you cannot customize much the result, hence the need for the static one. From the docs I see that actually one can override some actions, but it is not clear to me how far one can get. Let me give some examples of things that you can customize very easily in Django admin: which fields are displayed/editable on the list page; which ones are displayed/editable on the detail page; which ones are searchable/filtrable; how to sort items in the list page; which choices to restrict for foreign keys. Can one do this with...

Comment: ...dynamic sscaffolding without rewriting much of the functionality? I ask not to criticize, but because it is genuinely not clear to me how far scaffolding can be pushed.

Comment: The scaffolding constraints on domain objects can be used to eg. specify Which fields to display or hide. http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/Usage.html

And the template for scaffolding can be edited by you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291240/how-can-i-substitute-my-own-custom-dynamic-scaffolding-methods

Comment: Yes, but the constraints have another purpose, which is validation. And if you start editing the templates, you go into the path of code duplication that I mentioned in the question. What I am after is not scaffolding, rather some sort of customizable CRUD application.

Comment: Well, there are two types of constraints - some for validation - some for scaffolding. Have a look at the table at the bottom.

And I believe that you can modify the templates that are the basis of the dynamic scaffolding. That way there should be no code duplication, right? It is fine if you don't like the constraint+dynamic scaffolding templates solution, but I do think it is the Grails-y solution.